# MySQL Workbench error 1305 PROCEDURE doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to execute a statment in MySql to update a column in a table when the expiry date for one of the other columns surpasses the current date, this is then compared against something to make sure that there are no active people for it

but i keep getting this error , i can not see anything wrong with my syntax so im not sure what it is

Error 1305 PROCEDURE does not exist

```
UPDATE job j SET archived = 1 WHERE(SELECT count(*) FROM job_applied_candidates jac WHERE jac.jobID = j.id) = 0 AND enddate < now();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a space between `WHERE` an `(Select`...

Also check triggers on `jobs` table, since they could use a procedure that does not exist.

Comment: A space does not make a difference as there is a clear separator (the open parenthesis).

Comment: What about the triggers?

Comment: Triggers are a valid concern. My comment was just about the mentioned space, which doesn't make a difference.